# SSAS MDX - How to change the way summing up works in a cube?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

I want to change the way summing up works the cube to avoid rounding errors.

My calculation is simply Column A / Column B

At each level in the hierarchy, I want to have SUM(Column A) / Sum(Column B) instead of SUM(All the individual Column A / Column B)

How can I do this either in my calculation or changing the way the summing up works?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [calculated member](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Calculated%20Members.html) that is processed at the very end of the aggregation. Let's assume you defined A and B as measures :

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[A/B] AS  ([Measures].[A]) / ([Measures].[B])
SELECT
 ...
```

You can add the calculated member in the cube definition so it will be available in all mdx statements. To be sure, note Sum(A) / Sum(B) !=  Sum (A/B), you can add check for 0/null if needed.

Answer (score 1):

That you want is SUM(Column A) / Sum(Column B) instead of SUM(All the individual Column A / Column B). Then I asume that you have both measures: `sum_column_a` and `sum_column_b`.

To create new measure `sum_column_a_b` you should create a calculated member:

- On Visual Studio open your cube
- Click on calculations tab
- Click script view and paste this code:

Code to be pasted:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[sum_column_a_b]
 AS iif(  [Measures].[sum_column_b] > 0,
        [Measures].[sum_column_a] / [Measures].[sum_column_b], 
        0 ), 
FORMAT_STRING = "Percent", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'yourDesiredGroup';
```

When you process cube this new measure will be available.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you have a calculated field (Column A / Column B) in sql db or DSV (data source view). So, you can just create two SUM measures for each column (one sum measure for column A and second - for column B) and use them in the new calculated measure

`iif([Measure].[ColumnB]=0 OR [Measure].[ColumnB] is NULL, 0, [Measure].[ColumnA]/[Measure].[ColumnB])`.